# How can i get from format json this text?

Tags: python, file

I have a JSON file that contains several images and annotations.  Each image has an `id`, and each annotation references a caption and the `image_id` of the image.  There are thousands of images and multiple annotations refer to the same image.  Here's a sample for only one image and its annotations ([link to full data](https://vision.ece.vt.edu/mscoco/coco/annotations/captions_train2014.json)):

```json
{
  "images": [
    {
      "license": 5,
      "url": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3153/2970773875_164f0c0b83_z.jpg",
      "file_name": "COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg",
      "id": 57870,
      "width": 640,
      "date_captured": "2013-11-14 16:28:13",
      "height": 480
    }
  ],
  "annotations": [
    {
      "image_id": 57870,
      "id": 787980,
      "caption": "A restaurant has modern wooden tables and chairs."
    },
    {
      "image_id": 57870,
      "id": 789366,
      "caption": "A long restaurant table with rattan rounded back chairs."
    },
    {
      "image_id": 57870,
      "id": 789888,
      "caption": "a long table with a plant on top of it surrounded with wooden chairs "
    },
    {
      "image_id": 57870,
      "id": 791316,
      "caption": "A long table with a flower arrangement in the middle for meetings"
    },
    {
      "image_id": 57870,
      "id": 794853,
      "caption": "A table is adorned with wooden chairs with blue accents."
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to reconstruct the format of the text in this file to be like this:

```
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#0 A restaurant has modern wooden tables and chairs.
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#1 A long restaurant table with rattan rounded back chairs.
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#2 a long table with a plant on top of it surrounded with wooden chairs
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#3 A long table with a flower arrangement in the middle for meetings
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#4 A table is adorned with wooden chairs with blue accents.
```

I know the idea but couldn't write it in programming well using Python. I need first to check if the `image_id` is equal or not and if it is equal I need to get their ids and number it from 0 to 4 and get their captions.

Comment: None of the input (or output? Please be clear which is which) you show is valid JSON, so I can't understand the question. Please read [ask] and try to be clear - show exactly what is in which files before you run the program, exactly what should be in which files after you run the program (clearly labelled), exactly what *does* happen when you run the program, and explain how that is different from what you wanted.

Comment: json is too large to write the example here so i edit the post and write the link , can you check it ?

Comment: i want to get the first format from the second format so you can ignore json file but i wrote my tries if there is another solution better from than i wrote

Comment: None of the data you've shown is JSON. How do you expect us to help if you do not show your input(s)?

Comment: i put the link of json format and i mentioned that format is for captions_val2014.json !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading in the data, reorganizing into an dictionary indexed by ID will make it easy to access the correct image when iterating the annotations.  Below does this, but also adds each caption to a list of captions added to each image:

```py
import json

with open('captions_train2014.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Collect all images into a dictionary indexed by ID
images = {p['id']:p for p in data['images']}

# To each image, add a list of captions
for image in images.values():
    image['captions'] = []

# For each annotation, add its caption to its
# corresponding image's caption list.
for annotation in data['annotations']:
    image_id = annotation['image_id']
    annotation_id = annotation['id']
    images[image_id]['captions'].append(annotation['caption'])

# Iterate over images and print captions in the format requested.
for image in images.values():
    for i,caption in enumerate(image['captions']):
        print(f"{image['file_name']}#{i} {caption}")
```

Output:

```
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#0 A restaurant has modern wooden tables and chairs.
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#1 A long restaurant table with rattan rounded back chairs.
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#2 a long table with a plant on top of it surrounded with wooden chairs
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#3 A long table with a flower arrangement in the middle for meetings
COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg#4 A table is adorned with wooden chairs with blue accents.
COCO_train2014_000000384029.jpg#0 A man preparing desserts in a kitchen covered in frosting.
COCO_train2014_000000384029.jpg#1 A chef is preparing and decorating many small pastries.
COCO_train2014_000000384029.jpg#2 A baker prepares various types of baked goods.
COCO_train2014_000000384029.jpg#3 a close up of a person grabbing a pastry in a container
COCO_train2014_000000384029.jpg#4 Close up of a hand touching various pastries.
COCO_train2014_000000222016.jpg#0 a big red telephone booth that a man is standing in
COCO_train2014_000000222016.jpg#1 a person standing inside of a phone booth
COCO_train2014_000000222016.jpg#2 this is an image of a man in a phone booth.
COCO_train2014_000000222016.jpg#3 A man is standing in a red phone booth.
COCO_train2014_000000222016.jpg#4 A man using a phone in a phone booth.
 ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but if i want to do that for the images not a specific " if image_id is the same then it will be write the output format"

Comment: @user3188912 As I said very unclear what you wanted.

Comment: excuse me i tried to save it in a file and got `out.write(f"{image['file_name']}#{i} {caption}")`
                                                  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user3188912 Ask a new question with an example that reproduces the error.